# Determine if the cursor location is in a specific area of the screen

Tags: c#, telerik

I would like to know when my cursor is located within a specific aera ( a small rectangle for instance in the very right of the screen ).

When My cursor is in this aera, the form i'm dragging must have a higher height.

By now, i just have this :

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Cursor.Position == new Point(-1037, 516))
    {
        this.Height = 450;
    }

}
```

Thus, i need to create a condition to know if my cursor is located within a specific aera ( right of the screen )
Can anyone help me on this 
thanks in advance.

Comment: this is just a random point, difficult to find it on the screen... i don't know if it works or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cursor.Position` is in screen coordinates. You may test if the position is withing a specified range:

```
Const RANGE_X As Integer = 20;
Const RANGE_Y As Integer = 20;

if ( Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - RANGE_X <= Cursor.Position.X And _
     Cursor.Position.Y <= RANGE_Y )

   ' we're near the top right edge
```

**edit**: to test if the cursor is inside a border area, just like @Philip wrote:

```
Const BORDER_SIZE As Integer = 100;     ' In pixel
Rectangle border = new Rectangle(
    BORDER_SIZE, 
    BORDER_SIZE, 
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - BORDER_SIZE, 
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - BORDER_SIZE);  

If ( Not border.Contains(Cursor.Position) ) Then
    '  ... yes the cursor is in the border area
```

Comment: It works yes, thank you even if i don't really understand it...
How should i do to do something like this all around the screen ?

i mean, one inch all around the screen borders, the height is 800 for instance. for the rest of the screen ( outside the borders ), the height is 100

Thanks for your help

Comment: it's just pretty much the same, test if the cursor is in the border area.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
     //THE POSITION OF MY RECTANGLE HERE IS ON THE UPPER LEFT
     Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100); //CHANGE THIS DIMENSION TO YOUR LIKING
     if (rec.Contains(Cursor.Position))
     {
         //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
     }
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , it looks pretty good !
But nothing happens when i move my form on the screen...i don't know which part of the screen this rectangle represents actually... it's on the right ?



        private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100); //CHANGE THIS DIMENSION TO YOUR LIKING
            if (rec.Contains(pt))
            {
                this.Height = 450;
            }


        }

Comment: yeah my rectangle was on the left side sorry.. you can change it to the right just change the dimension (X,Y,Width,Height)

Comment: were u able to make it work? i hope so if not.. im willing to help

Comment: @PhilipBadilla why create a new point? What's wrong with `rec.Contains(Cursor.Position)` ?

Comment: @rotem you are right.. haha.. i forgot it also returns a point.. i stand corrected... i wrote it in a hurry so i stand corrected... let me edit it